# Operator precedence with LR(0) parser

Tags: parsing, operators, bnf, lr-grammar, associativity

A typical BNF defining arithmetic operations:

```
E :- E + T
  |  T
T :- T * F
  |  F
F :- ( E )
  | number
```

Is there any way to re-write this grammar so it could be implemented with an LR(0) parser, while still retaining the precedence and left-associativity of the operators? 
I'm thinking it should be possible by introducing some sort of disambiguation non-terminals, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while since I did parser theory, but isn't that already an lalr(1) grammar? (and if so, isn't creating an lr(0) parser just grunt work?)

Comment: It could be that it is, or it may be just SLR. I am curios as to whether there are any workarounds to shift/reduce problems like these. Seems like alot of trouble to have to implement LALR for simple arithmetics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A language can only have an LR(0) grammar if it's *prefix-free*, meaning that no string in the language is a prefix of another. In this case, the language you're describing isn't prefix-free. For example, the string `number + number` is a prefix of `number + number + number`.

A common workaround to address this would be to "endmark" your language by requiring all strings generated to end in a special "done" character. For example, you could require that all strings generated end in a semicolon. If you do that, you can build an LR(0) parser for the language with this grammar:

> S → E;
>
> E → E + T | T
>
> T → T * F | F
>
> F → number | (E)